# Regex: match sequence of not a certain string

Tags: python, regex

```
s = 'blah blah blah... _ABC_superman_is_cool_CBA_ ...blah blah blah...'
```

This is just an example, but I want to match everything between _ABC_ and _CBA_. So 'superman_is_cool'. There may be multiple sections of _ABC_..._CBA_.

```
re.findall('_ABC_(.*)(?=_CBA_)', s)
```

I tried this first, but obviously doesn't correctly work at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I added an additional `_ABC_`, `_CBA_` pair to make sure it finds all the matches:

```
>>> s = 'blah blah blah... _ABC_superman_is_cool_CBA_ ...blah blah _ABC_blah_CBA_...'
>>> re.findall('_ABC_(.*?)_CBA_', s)
['superman_is_cool', 'blah']
```

The `?` makes the `*` operator non-greedy so it finds as short a match as possible. Without it  the result would be `['superman_is_cool_CBA_ ...blah blah _ABC_blah']`.

Comment: +1 for not getting bitten by greediness ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
re.findall('_ABC_.*_CBA_)', s)
```

Comment: That's not a valid regular expression..